# How to send 2 variables to a second PHP page using get

Tags: php

I had some help yesterday on passing a variable to a PHP page (Thanks). I now am stuck again.

Scenario - I am new so I know there is an easier way but at the moment I have a database that I want to query. Page 0 - I select a place (Called 'categorynum' [ I then pass that to page 1 (Which is the code below where it pulls in the categorynum from previous page and allows me to select a date. I now want to pass that date (categoryevent) and place (categorynum) to page 2. The below code passes categoryevent no problem but what am I doing wrong as its only passing the text of categorynum over.

CODE for page 1

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    <p>Date of Investigation:</p>
    <select name="categoryevent">
<?php
    foreach ($catByDate as $num=> $event){
        print "<option value=\"$event\">$event</option>\n";
    
    }
?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name='categorynum' value='$categorynum'>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Summary">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you look in `$_GET['categoryevent']`

Comment: Or maybe you need a name attribute on this line `<input type="submit" name="something" value="Show Summary">`

Comment: _"its only passing the text of categorynum over"_ - well that's because you put the _static text_ `$categorynum` into the value attribute. You are not in a PHP string context there, as you are with `print "<option value=\"$event\">$event</option>\n";` above in the loop. So you'll want something like `value='<?php echo $categorynum; ?>'` in that place. (That of course still lacks any context-appropiate handling/escaping of the data.)

Comment: Are you getting a dropdown filled with dates on the page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am getting the dropdown no problem and when i select something that (categoryevent) is being passed to page2. I want to forward on categorynum which i used to create the dropdown from the previous page to also send to page2. So categoryevent is fine. it is just the repassing of categorynum I am struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh now I see it. You are not actually loading the value of `$categorynum` into the hidden input.

So change how you set the value into the input element

```
<input type="hidden" name='categorynum' value='<?php echo $categorynum; ?>'>
```